# Error: Configuration is not defined: topic

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

My Kafka Connect is sitting in a Kubernetes cluster which has the `mongo-kafka-connect-1.1.0-all.jar` in the connectors folder.

I have port forwarded the Kafka Connect service to my localhost and am trying to upload the properties for a Mongo Sink Connector with this curl command (obviously, with my own connection details in the relevant `<>` places):

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink-mongodb/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
      "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "topics":"<topic name>",
      "connection.uri":"mongodb://<username>:<password>@<uri1>:<port1>,<uri2>:<port2>",
      "database":"<database name>",
      "collection":"<collection name>",
      "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable":false,
      "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable":false
}'
```

However, I get the following error response:

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nConfiguration is not defined: topic\nUnable to connect to the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

Is my config wrong, am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe just a typo: instead of `topics` use `topic` in your command.

Comment: Thanks @mike for the suggestion, but it is definitely `topics`. If I change it to `topic`, I get an error: `{"error_code":500,"message":"Must configure one of topics or topics.regex"}`

Comment: Did you find the issue ? I am facing the same issue and cant figure out the solutions @David

Comment: @yantrakaar Unfortunately, not! I have for the moment had to leave this issue to focus on other things that are not blocked by this. Unless I get some help from someone, I'll most likely need to work out an alternative method potentially not using Kafka Connect. Maybe by writing a producing and consuming FaaS, but this is not preferred because it will lose the benefits of Kafka Connect.

Comment: @David In my case the connection.uri parameter was failing hence the error_count was 1. It seems there is a bug while sending response of validation. so the value "Configuration is not defined: topic" is always appended in the response of validation even if validation succeeds.

Comment: I have revisited my `connection.uri` but I do not see what is wrong with it. Those details allow me to connect in MongoDB Compass.

Comment: @David Did you happen to resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Djeah, I have not resolved it, and unfortunately needed to find an alternative architecture, because of it. I still would like to solve this at some point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end, the issue was that the I needed to take the `.pem` file and convert it to a `.crt` and add this to the server's list of CAs. Essentially the server didn't accept the SSL cert and was refusing to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 1.0.1 instead of 1.1.0 — that is, mongo-kafka-connect-1.0.1-all.jar — as the plugin, and this error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Changing docker image from mongo:4.0.xenial to mongo:4.0.4 resolved the issue.